# How to make SQL query result show with 2 Decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've stumbled into an issue to get this code to show results with only 2 decimals

```
SELECT 
SUM(CAST(
Size * 8 as Decimal)/1024
) as [Size in MB]

FROM 
sysfiles
```

As for now it returns the size of my database with 7 decimals :/

Comment: `cast(xxx as decimal(12,2))`

Comment: Thanks.. i didnt see that you wrote, and meanwhile I found out myself :D

Answer (score 0):

I would advise converting to a decimal format with two places:

```
select convert(decimal(20, 2), size * 8.0/1024) as [Size in MB]
from sysfiles;
```

This converts the value to the right *type*.  However, if you want to ensure that the value is displayed to the right precision/scale, then you can use `format()` or `str()`:

```
select str(size * 8.0/1024, 20, 2) as [Size in MB]
from sysfiles;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast decimal with just `cast(xxx as decimal({length},{precision}))`

```
SELECT 
SUM(CAST(
Size * 8 as Decimal(20,2))/1024
) as [Size in MB]

FROM 
sysfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

just cast the sum itself to decimal

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CAST(Size * 8 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) /  1024) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) [Size in MB]
```